# Audio CD 16 bit or 24 bit?

Tags: audio, bit-depth, cd

I want to create my own audio CD. Should I render WAV files to 16 bit or 24 bit depth?

Answer (score 6):

Audio CDs are encoded with 16-bit values. Higher bitrates are generally used for editing, not for playback. You can write 24-bit WAV files to an optical disc, of course, but it will not be a standards complying audio CD.

Comment: 16 bits like the man says but don't forget to dither when rendering. It helps a bit in quieter passages of music.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are mixing/mastering 24bit (as you should be) I would create a 24bit master & then create a 16bit AudioCD version, dithered down from the 24 bit

Comment: Who's mixing/mastering in 24bit these days? It's all 32 or 64-bit floating point now, you don't even get to choose anything lower because it wouldn't make sense (modern processors handle a `double` as fast as anything else, and integers are useless for any nontrivial effects plugin). 24-bit is merely standard for _recorded audio files_, mainly because that's what the ADCs offer.